# Multi set in c++ and oops

Tags: c++, c++14

Start with the person class, and create a multiset to hold pointers to person
objects. Define the multiset with the comparePersons function object, so it will
be sorted automatically by names of persons. Define a half-dozen persons, put
them in the multiset, and display its contents. Several of the persons should 
have the same name, to verify that the multiset stores multiple objects with the
same key.

**PROBLEM:** I am unable to sort the multiset and I am not sure why.

Code:
// sorts person objects stored by pointer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <set> //addded---------------------------------------------
using namespace std;

class person
{
private:
   string lastName;
   string firstName;
   long phoneNumber;
public:
   // default constructor
   person() :lastName("blank"), firstName("blank"), phoneNumber(0L)
   { }
   // 3-arg constructor
   person(string lana, string fina, long pho) :
       lastName(lana), firstName(fina), phoneNumber(pho)
   { }
   friend bool operator<(const person&, const person&);
   friend bool operator==(const person&, const person&);

   void display() const // display person's data
   {
       cout << endl << lastName << ",\t" << firstName
           << "\t\tPhone: " << phoneNumber;
   }
   long get_phone() const // return phone number
   {
       return phoneNumber;
   }
}; //end class person
//--------------------------------------------------------------
// overloaded < for person class
bool operator<(const person& p1, const person& p2)
{
   if (p1.lastName == p2.lastName)
       return (p1.firstName < p2.firstName) ? true : false;
   return (p1.lastName < p2.lastName) ? true : false;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
// overloaded == for person class
bool operator==(const person& p1, const person& p2)
{
   return (p1.lastName == p2.lastName &&
       p1.firstName == p2.firstName) ? true : false;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
// function object to compare persons using pointers
class comparePersons
{
public:
   bool operator() (const person* ptrP1, const person* ptrP2) const
   {
       return *ptrP1 < *ptrP2;
   }
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------
//function object to display a person, using a pointer
class displayPerson
{
public:
   void operator() (const person* ptrP) const
   {
       ptrP->display();
   }
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{   
   //make persons
   person* ptrP1 = new person("KuangThu", "Bruce", 4157300);
   person* ptrP2 = new person("Deauville", "William", 8435150);
   person* ptrP3 = new person("Wellington", "John", 9207404);
   person* ptrP4 = new person("Bartoski", "Peter", 6946473);
   person* ptrP5 = new person("Fredericks", "Roger", 7049982);
   person* ptrP6 = new person("McDonald", "Stacey", 7764987);
   person* ptrP7 = new person("KuangThu", "Bruce", 4157300);
   person* ptrP8 = new person("Deauville", "William", 8435150);

   //Creating multiset
   multiset<person*> multiPtrsPers;
   multiPtrsPers.insert(ptrP1);
   multiPtrsPers.insert(ptrP2);
   multiPtrsPers.insert(ptrP3);
   multiPtrsPers.insert(ptrP4);
   multiPtrsPers.insert(ptrP5);
   multiPtrsPers.insert(ptrP6);
   multiPtrsPers.insert(ptrP7);
   multiPtrsPers.insert(ptrP8);

   for_each(multiPtrsPers.begin(),multiPtrsPers.end(), displayPerson());//display person
   cout << endl;

   sort(multiPtrsPers.begin(), multiPtrsPers.end(), comparePersons());//compare persons

   for_each(multiPtrsPers.begin(), multiPtrsPers.end(), displayPerson());//display persons
   cout << endl;

   system("pause");
   return 0;
} end main()
```

Comment: please do not spam tags. You only need to tag a specific version of the c++ standard when you are bound to that standard (and it isnt the current one). Which version of c++ are you using?

Comment: c++14 and i want to solve my query asap thats why i tagged

Comment: `bool operator() (const person* ptrP1, const person* ptrP2) const
   {
       return *ptrP1 < *ptrP2;
   }` That's a rather "odd" `operator()` you have there...

Comment: @abcd: Adding more tags doesn't necessarily get you answers faster.

Comment: "i want to solve my query asap thats why i tagged" ... any question is answered as soon as possible, spamming tags doesnt help on that. But this question is also not answered any more asap as any other quesiton...

Comment: "i want to solve my query asap thats why i tagged" - Your urgency is *no* concern of ours, nor the future viability/relevance of the question.

Comment: you got an answer that should work, but note that you go through quite some hoops just to have pointers in the container which gains you nothing but lots of memory leaking and quite some boilerplate. Unless there is a good reason that is not apparent from the question you should store objects not pointers (at the very least use smart pointers)

Comment: If you could help me write the code it would be great :)

Comment: Clear question tends to be answered faster as there are easier to understand and to point issue. Spamming tags, and asking for answer ASAP, tends to be downvoted, and/or zapped by some people. Inverse effect.

Comment: @abcd "If you could help me write the code it would be great" - That's *not* how Stackoverflow works. We're *not* a free code-writing service.

Comment: @abcd "There are many more helpful people around the world. And if someone is in problem there is no harm to help them" - How is comment *at all* relevant?

Comment: You are not a "free code writer" but some people are willing to help for example Jorad42.You could be like him it feels good to help

Answer (score 2):

Your comparer should go in multiset type:

```
multiset<person*, comparePersons> multiPtrsPers;
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a638d1d03910fa4)

(multi)set cannot be reordered by other comparison afterward.
You cannot call `sort` on that container.

Comment: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|1969|error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<person*>' and 'std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<person*>')|   Getting this error now

Comment: Read the full answer, you cannot call `std::sort`.

Answer (score 1):

Sets cannot be `sort`ed because they use an internal ordering in order to quickly locate and insert elements. Sorting the set externally would break this.

Instead, if you refer to [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset), you find that you can adjust the ordering yourself:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class multiset;
```

Which means that what you want is:

```
std::multiset<person*, comparePersons> multiPtrsPers;
```